# Integrate $\int \dfrac{\ln(x)}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}\text{d}x$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate  $\int \dfrac{\ln(x)}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}\text{d}x$

How can I solve that integral, only applying simple substitution, and by parts. It cannot be done any other way, I already did it by trigonometric and it comes out easy.

**My try**: Notice that,  $$\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left ( \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right )=\dfrac{1}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$$

Let $u=\ln x$, then $\text{d}u=\dfrac{1}{x}\text{d}x$. And, let $\text{d}v=\dfrac{1}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$. By (1) we have to  $v=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    \int \dfrac{\ln(x)}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}\text{d}x&=\dfrac{x\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\int \dfrac{x}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\text{d}x\\
    &=\dfrac{x\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\text{d}x\\
    &=\dfrac{x\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\arcsin(x)+C.
\end{align*}

Comment: 1. You may want to elaborate. What substitution have you tried? Where are you stuck? 2. Consider checkmarking somw answers to your previous questions. It shows that you one. have appreciated their help and two. it immediatly shows that the question is answered.

Comment: But, there is another way to justify that this derivative gives that. Because regardless of that, I don't know how to do it. That is the step that I have not been able to justify in a good way.

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez That is essentially the answer I have given you . . .

Answer (score 5):

To begin with, if we make the substitution $x = \sin(u)$, we get:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1-x^{2})^{3/2}} = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\cos^{2}(u)} = \tan(u) = \frac{\sin(u)}{\cos(u)} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}
\end{align*}

Hence we can apply integration by parts in order to obtain:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\ln(x)}{(1-x^{2})^{3/2}}\mathrm{d}x & = \frac{x\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\\\
& = \frac{x\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} - \arcsin(x) + c
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: But that is trigonometric substitution, and the question is to do it only with simple substitution.

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez This post doesn't answer your question but it provides the fastest way to calculate the integral. I'd have an idea how you can solve it without trigonometric functions but it would be a unnecessarily harder.